# basicGet and basicAck in different threads in RabbitMQ

Tags: java, rabbitmq

Can we call basicGet to get message from RabbitMQ, then process it asynchronously and call basicAck in another thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can and it is also a common practise.

Comment: Am I right that I can't use channel.basicConsume("queueName", false, consumer); and send ack in thread different to the consumer thread? I've read everywhere that channel represends a Unit-of-Work and "it is highly recommended to use a different
channel for each thread"

Comment: People don't write much about basicGet. In your book you are only saying that it can be used to peek the queue. Could you tell in what other cases it's worth to use basicGet?

Comment: To clarify, we're talking about threads, not channels, right? I think if the question said "channel" instead of "thread", the answer might be different?

Comment: Yes, we are talking about Threads. I can explain my case. I want to read messages from a queue and then process them asynchronously in my own thread pool, consumer will send messages further via async http client. So I'll get response in another thread (not the same thread that I used to read the message from the channel). And after I get async http reply I want to send Ack. What I'm afraid is that it can lead to some unpredictable errors, because everybody insists on using Channels binded to one constant thread.

Comment: @EugeneTo In your case it is better to use `basic_consume`. you case use the same channel to send the ack between the threads. please read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30695375/rabbitmq-and-channels-java-thread-safety

Comment: this doesn't work well (sometimes some racing conditions makes connection to be closed)

Comment: @dimzon no, it works. The connection is closed for some bug in the code or problem in the network, not for the basicAck.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but you have to pass the channel reference, otherwise it won't work